# Update canvas dimensions as window is reshaped.

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize, html5-canvas

I have a HTML canvas set to the height and width of the window in JavaScript. However, if the window is reshaped, the canvas size stays the same unless the page is refreshed.

Comment: So, umm, trap the window's `resize` event....

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically resize the canvas, you can add an event listener to check if the window has been resized. Then you can redraw your canvas.

```
        function initialize() {
            // Register an event listener to
            // call the resizeCanvas() function each time 
            // the window is resized.
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

            // Draw canvas border for the first time.
            resizeCanvas();
        }

        // Display custom canvas.
        // In this case it's a blue, 5 pixel border that 
        // resizes along with the browser window.                   
        function redraw() {
            context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            context.lineWidth = '5';
            context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        // Runs each time the DOM window resize event fires.
        // Resets the canvas dimensions to match window,
        // then draws the new borders accordingly.
        function resizeCanvas() {
            htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            redraw();
        }
```

For further details on how this works, here's an excellent blog post that lists out all steps - http://htmlcheats.com/html/resize-the-html5-canvas-dyamically/

Comment: then you _MUST_ redraw your canvas, because resizing them automatically clears them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a Javascript window resize listener to set the size of the canvas programmatically when the window size has been changed.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    redraw(); // you must handle the redraw yourself
};
```

You will just have to adjust the `width` and `height` of the canvas, making sure you `redraw()` in a custom method.

Check out this basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/099pn07n/) to show a basic implementation of this.

**Of note:**

You can set the CSS `height` and `width` of a canvas element, which works as expected.

```
canvas {
    width: 50%;
}
```

The issue with doing is that if you specify both a `width` and `height`, this can create distortion in whatever is drawn on the canvas. If you only specify one property, however, the canvas will scale proportionally. Depending on the use case for your `canvas`, this might be an okay way of going about doing it.

Comment: NB: the former will end up using CSS scaling to rescale the canvas, without redrawing its contents.  This will probably look poor.

Comment: Agreeing with Alnitak...and it will look poor because resizing with CSS will distort the canvas content unless the resizing is done with the same aspect ratio as the original canvas. ...and resizing more than about 2X times will pixelate the canvas content. A better way is to resize the canvas element itself: canvas.width=newWidth, etc. Resizing the canvas element will clear its contents, so you will have to redraw that content.